# How to test ModelForm save() method saves changes in model?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-testing, django-modeladmin

I have overridden `AdminModel`'s `ModelForm` to make `User` fields edible and savable from `Person`'s admin change form.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #and also some char, text fields

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.user.first_name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, value):
        self.user.first_name = value

    #and by analogy surname and email properties


class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    surname = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(PersonForm, self).save(commit)  
        user = instance.user
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['surname']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.save()
        return instance

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'surname', 'email', 'and_others']

    form = PersonForm

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

However I am struggling with writing a test that checks save() method:

```
def test_form_saves_values_to_instance_user_on_save(self):
    """
    test that, form saves name, surname, email values to corresponding User
    when commiting form
    """
    user = User.objects.get(username='admin')
    person = Person.objects.get(user=user)
    personform = PersonForm(instance=person, data={'name': 'has_changed'})

    # if uncommented raisesValueError: The Person could not be changed
    # because the data didn't validate.
    # personform.save()

    self.assertEquals("has_changed", User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).first_name)
```

**upd** test

**upd** solution. It turned out that I had unfilled requested invisible field 'user'. Exclusion made form valid and test passing.

admin.py

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)
# ...
```

tests.py

```
def test_form_saves_values_to_instance_user_on_save(self):
    """
    test that, form saves name, surname, email values to corresponding User
    when commiting form
    """

    person = Person.objects.get(user__username='admin')
    personform = PersonForm(instance=person, data={'name': 'has_changed'})

    if personform.is_valid():
        person = personform.save()
        self.assertEquals(User.objects.get(pk=person.user.pk).first_name, "has_changed")
    else:
        self.fail("personform not valid")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def test_form_saves_values_to_instance_user_on_save(self):
    """
    test form saves name, surname, email values to corresponding User object
    when commiting form
    """
    person = Person.objects.get(user__username='admin')
    personform = PersonForm(instance=person, data={'name': 'has_changed'})

    if personform.is_valid():
        person = personform.save()
        self.assertEquals(person.user.first_name, "has_changed")
    else:
        self.fail("personform not valid")
```

I think you also need to exclude the `user` field from your form

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ('user',)
    ...
```

Comment: This returns `ValueError: The Person could not be changed because the data didn't validate.`

Comment: `self.assertEquals(user.first_name, "has_changed")` will by definition fail, as the data in `user` is not reloaded from the database, so it cannot be changed.

Comment: How to make personform valid or what made it invalid?

Comment: @knbk fixed now I think

Comment: i just did not include 'user' in fields

Comment: ah, didn't notice that in the model admin class :)

Comment: 'user' field is not present now on my form. But it is steel probably a good idea to exclude field explicitly.

Comment: The test above fails with "personform not valid". How to make it pass?

Comment: well I have to assume you have some fields on the `Person` model that become required in `PersonForm`, so you need to supply some additional values in the `data` dict

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68842/discussion-between---and-anentropic).

Comment: You were right not putting field `user` into `AdminModel` fields list makes field `user` invisible, but does not imply exclusion. I set exclude strictly as you suggested and then test worked for me. Thank you, @knbk and @Anentropic

Answer (score 1):

Pass the new data as a dictionary to your form (as first positional argument or as `data`), and assert that `personform.cleaned_data['name']` is equal to `User.objects.get(pk=user.pk).username`. Then do the same for `surname` and `email`.

Note that `first_name` and `last_name` have a `max_length` of 30, while your form fields have a `max_length` of 100.